# Dropping everything in a database owned by a certain role -- not working

Tags: postgresql, permissions, delete, role

I want to delete everything in a certain database owned by a certain role. I've tried to do and nothing has been deleted.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \l
                                      List of databases
          Name           |   Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |    Access privileges    
-------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------------------
 my_db123                | web_user1 | UTF8     | C       | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/web_user1          +
                         |           |          |         |         | web_user1=CTc/web_user1
 postgres                | postgres  | UTF8     | C       | C.UTF-8 | 
 template0               | postgres  | UTF8     | C       | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres            +
                         |           |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1               | postgres  | UTF8     | C       | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres            +
                         |           |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

And

```
# drop owned by web_user1;
```

But then I connect to `my_db123` and everything is it still remains - all the tables, all data in them.

Why have they not been deleted? And how to do it properly then?

I also want that after I delete everythin in a database, any newly object in that database to be owned the same user - `web_user1`. I used these commands to create a database initially:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db123 WITH OWNER web_user1;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db123 TO web_user1;
```

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL documentation:

> DROP OWNED drops all the objects within the **current database** that are owned by one of the specified roles.

You have to connect to `my_db123` first.